# how to execute statements only after junit reports are generated by TESTNG?

Tags: junit, automated-tests, testng

I'm converting junit reports generated by testng to some other format.

I've written this code to do so:

```
@AfterTest
public void execute()
{
    String junitReport = "TEST-"+this.getClass().getCanonicalName()+".xml";
    TestManagerLogger obj = new TestManagerLogger();
    obj.convertLog(junitReport);

}
```

But this doesn't work as reports are not generated before the execution of this method.
Is there any way by which this method can be called only after report generation?

My test Case :

```
@Test(dataProvider = "jobCount")
public void testJobCount(String Scenario, String URL,String methodType, String status) {
    URL = URL.replaceFirst("ip", ip);
    String logonToken=LogonUtility.logon();
    String result=  ResponseGenerator.response(URL, logonToken, methodType);
    List<HashMap> valuesFromExcel = StringSplitter.getKeyValuePairs(status);// Returns hashmap containing key values ex: failed =0 , total =3
    List<HashMap> valuesFromRest = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    Document doc = StringSplitter.convertStringToDocument(result);
    javax.xml.xpath.XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList node,node1;
    try{
        node =(NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/feed/entry/content/attrs/attr[@name='status_type']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        node1 = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("/feed/entry/content/attrs/attr[@name='count']", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();

        for(int i=0;i<node.getLength();i++)
        {
            hm.put(node.item(i).getTextContent(),node1.item(i).getTextContent() );
        }
        valuesFromRest.add(hm);
        if(valuesFromRest.equals(valuesFromExcel))
        {
            AssertJUnit.assertTrue(true);

        }
        else
        {
            AssertJUnit.assertTrue(false);
        }


    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Expected XML Report

```
<logfile>
<logrecord>
    <case>scenario</case>
    <etime>Execution time</etime>
</logrecord>
</logfile>
```

Scenario is passed as a parameter in testcase

Comment: You will have to use CI like jenkins to achieve this , as it provide option to execute action like post build.  For testng @AfterTest is also part of execution so it never understand way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should instead do is to implement your own reporter: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters

```
public class TestManagerReporter implements IReporter {

  public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
    // print <logfile>
    for (ISuite suite : suites) {
      for (IInvokedMethod method : suite.getAllInvokedMethods()) {
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
          ITestResult result = method.getTestResult();
          if (result.getStatus() == SUCCESS) {
            // print <logrecord>
            // print <case>
            // print result.getName()
            // print </case>
            // print <etime>
            // print result.getEndMillis() - result.getStartMillis() 
            // print </etime>
            // print </logrecord>
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // print </logfile>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the document but couldn't do much from there. would really help a lot if you can tell me where i can find detailed example.

Comment: The idea is to generate your own format from the TestNG model object instead to use an intermediate format (junit). If you want help, you should share the expected format.

Comment: I've added the expected xml report format in the question.

Comment: Ok, I added an example of what you can do to generated the expected format. There are many other ways to do it, just check the TestNG API. I let you to complete the xml generating part.

Comment: thanks for the example, started working on this. I just wanted to ask you one more question.I'm using eclipse to run my test class, without configuring testng.xml, Will this class be invoked automatically after test case execution ?

Comment: It has to be declared as a listener. Check the documentation to find how you prefer to do it

Comment: And yes, reporters are called after the run of all tests.

Comment: In your code, result.getName() returns the the name of the test method. What i need is the "scenario" that is passed as a parameter to the test method. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You can try by implementing `ITest` and with `result.getTestName() `: http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITest.html OR you can look for it in `result.getParameters()`.